# Change comparison operators without large conditional block

Tags: c++, logical-operators, comparison-operators

I am testing whether a number lies between two values. I leave it up to the user to choose whether the logical comparison should include an `equal to` on either (or both) of the limits or not. 
They set this by defining a `struct`which contains the two edge values and which comparison operator to use:

```
typedef struct {
    double low; 
    double high;
    bool low_equal; //false if a greater than operator (`>`) should be used, true if a greater-than-or-equal-to (`>=`) operator should be used
    bool high_equal; //Same as low_equal but for a less-than operator
} Edges;
```

An array of `Edges` is created, (termed `bins` below) and for each input `value` I check whether it lies within the bin edges. 
However, in order to use the desired pair of comparison operators, I've ended up with this hideous conditional block:

```
        if (bins[j].low_equal && bins[j].high_equal)
        {
            if (value >= bins[j].low && value <= bins[j].high)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (bins[j].low_equal)
        {
            if (value >= bins[j].low && value < bins[j].high)
            {
                data[i] = bins[j].value;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (bins[j].high_equal)
        {
            if (datum > bins[j].low && datum <= bins[j].high)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (value > bins[j].low && value < bins[j].high)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can I somehow set the operators to use and then just call them?

Comment: You can use `std::function` and the operator function equivalents like e.g. `std::less`, `std::less_equal`, etc.

Comment: @jramm what if the value matches more than one element in your array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach could be:

```
bool higher = (value > bins[j].low) || (bins[j].low_equal && value == bins[j].low); 
bool lower  = (value < bins[j].high) || (bins[j].high_equal && value == bins[j].high); 

if (higher && lower)
{
    // In range
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use pointer on function

```
bool less(double lhs, double rhs) { return lhs < rhs; }
bool less_or_equal(double lhs, double rhs) { return lhs <= rhs; }
using comp_double = bool(double, double);
```

and then

```
comp_double *low_comp = bins[j].low_equal ? less_or_equal : less;
comp_double *high_comp = bins[j].high_equal ? less_or_equal : less;

if (low_comp(bins[j].low, value) && high_comp(value, bins[j].high)) {
   // In range
}
```

Comment: No need to define something like `less` yourself, there are already standard functions `std::less` etc.

Comment: I see, also it's C++14.

Answer (score 1):

This would be IMO a good case for the ternary operator

```
if ((bins[j].low_equal ? bins[j].low <= value : bins[j].low < value) &&
    (bins[j].high_equal ? value <= bins[j].high : value < bins[j].high)) {
   ...
}
```